# Setting the extended file attributes using SSH.NET SftpClient

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, openssh, ssh.net

I am trying to use the extended file attribute to store some information after I uploaded a file into remote machine (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) from Windows using Renci SSH.NET SFTP library. But the attributes are not getting preserved?

This how I am trying to set the extended attributes

```
SftpFileAttributes fileAttrs = sftpClient.GetAttributes(remoteFilePath);
IDictionary<string, string> additionalAttrs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
additionalAttrs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user.from", "abc"));
additionalAttrs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user.to", "xyz"));
fileAttrs =
    new SftpFileAttributes(
        fileAttrs.LastAccessTime, fileAttrs.LastWriteTime, fileAttrs.Size,
        fileAttrs.UserId, fileAttrs.GroupId, 222, additionalAttrs);
sftpClient.SetAttributes(remoteFilePath, fileAttrs);
```

So, can you help me how to approach this problem? **Note that**: The remote machine is configured to allow only SFTP connection for security reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add random extended attributes like `user.from`. You can add only attributes that **your server** explicitly supports.

You didn't specify what SFTP server are you using. But as you are connecting to Ubuntu server, one can assume, that it's the the most widespread *nix SFTP server, OpenSSH. And OpenSSH **does not support any extended attribute**. It *silently* ignores all of them.

---

See also these discussions:

- [Implementation of xattr in sftp-server for sshfs](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1953) (OpenSSH)
- [Support extended attribute SFTP requests](https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/issues/241) (ProFTPD)
- [Read file extended attributes of files on SFTP server with JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58301307/850848)

And the relevant section of SFTP specification:

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02#section-5