# Read file attributes of any file available at server without downloading it

Tags: java, file-io, jsch

We have one SFTP server where we placed one file present in **./test/directory1/test.csv**.
We added one custom attribute to this file before placing it to this directory , attribute name **"user.customchecksum"**, below is code which we used to add attribute

```
Path file = Paths.get("C:/Files/test.csv");
            UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(file,
                    UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
            view.write("user.customchecksum", Charset.defaultCharset().encode("XDRSECTVVTEST"));
```

Now before downloading this file we want to check that this attribute value and after that only we download this file.

**Note**::
For connection we are using JSCH and able to get File Inputstream without downloading the file.
Below method we are using to read file attribute value after file is downloaded.
But now we want to read this attribute before downloading file.

```
    private void getCustomAttributes(String filePath) {
    try {
        Path file = Paths.get(filePath);
        UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(file, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
        String name = "user.customchecksum";
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(view.size(name));

        view.read(name, buf);
        buf.flip();
        String value = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(buf).toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

We are able to read file InputStream before downloading file, can this be used to read added attributes? if yes what is the way to do this?

Comment: What "custom attribute"? Do you mean something like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes ?

Comment: Yes, we added one attribute by using this code: Path file = Paths.get(filePath);
    UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(file,
      UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
    view.write("user.customchecksum", Charset.defaultCharset().encode("XDRSECTVVTEST"));

Comment: I updated my question  as well the way we are adding attributes to a file.

Comment: If I understand correctly you use something like [`ChannelSftp.get()`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.55/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#get(java.lang.String)) to get the file content? It seems to me that simply using [the `lstat` method](https://javadoc.io/static/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.55/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#lstat(java.lang.String)) of that same class should give you access to what you need.

Comment: See [Read file extended attributes of files on SFTP server with JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58301307/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl so is this not possible ?

Comment: I believe my answer to the linked question answers this comprehensively. TL;DR: In most cases, it's imo not possible using SFTP. It still might be possible "using JSch", if you resort to using shell commands (and know what shell commands to use, but that's not a programing question anymore, imo).